# Using perf for the linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, perf

I know how to use `perf` command to analyze a binary file or a running process. I would like to know if it is possible to *perf the kernel itself* or not. I didn't find a clear answer for that. Does that mean I have to profile init process? How about profiling the linux scheduler. Then how can I do that?

Comment: You can run `perf record` in system-wide mode with events counting only in kernel mode, `--all-kernel`.  Or a `:k` modifier makes an event count only in kernel space, like `cycles:k`.  (`man perf-list`)

Comment: I use `perf record -e cycles:u -j any,u -a -o perf.data -p 12324` for my analysis. Do you mean changing `u` to `k` only?

Comment: I guess even with `:k`, I have to specify a binary or a running process. That is my question exactly. What to profile?

Comment: With system-wide, just a `sleep 60` works fine.  Or you can actually omit any target at all if you use `-a` with `perf stat` or `perf record`; read the man page

Comment: The `-a` option should already profile all cores, just remove `-p 12324`. You might need to run the command as `root` if you don't have [`/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html#perf-event-paranoid) correctly set up.

Comment: I ran `sudo perf record -a -o perf.data sleep 60` and the file size is small. See `[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.567 MB perf.data (2807 samples) ]
`

Comment: Well then it works! If you think it's not collecting enough data it's pretty hard to tell what's wrong given the limited amount of information you give (almost none). I would suggest updating the question adding as much details as possible.

Comment: If I now run my binary file and the collect data with `-a`, I think I will have more data since the binary uses files, networks and other kernel related staffs. I guess `sleep 60` has nothing to do with kernel and therefore the kernel activity is low. That is a guess. I would like to know if you are agree with that or not.

Comment: Well... yes, surely that has something to do with it. If you run a process that does a lot of syscalls then of course kernel activity will increase compared to a process like `sleep 60` which basically does nothing for 60 seconds.